# If $A$ is positive definite, then $B^TA^{-1}B$ is also positive/negative (semi) definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

probably this is a basic question, but I can not see it clearly.

If $A \succ 0$, then $B^TA^{-1}B$ is also positive/negative (semi) definite? or in general is undefined?

In addition, you can assume that $B$ is full column rank.

Comment: Consider contraposition. $x^TB^TA^{-1}Bx<0$ implies $y^TA^{-1}y<0$ (where $y=Bx$) implies $A^{-1}$ is not positive semidefinite implies $A$ is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: It would be an interesting problem if the matrices are complex. $B^HA^{-1}B$ is easy to prove positive/negative semidefinite (for arbitrary $B$), but how about $B^T A^{-1} B$ in the complex case ...

Comment: Stan, I have specified it. But in my problem you can assume that the elements are real numbers. Furthermore, in my problem, you can assume that $B$ is square with the same dimensions as $A$

Comment: @noether: anon has given the answer to your problem. I just add some matters needing attention. In fact, if the matrices are complex, not all $B^T A^{-1} B$ are (semi)definite. So you ***have to*** assume the elements are real to prove the (semi)definite property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which definition of $A>0$ do you use?
Let $V$ be arbitrary inner product space. We say a linear map $A$ is pos.definite, if $A=A^*$ and for $x\in V$, $x\neq 0$ we have $\langle x,Ax\rangle>0$. Since $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$, $I=A^*(A^{-1})^*=A(A^{-1})^*$, so the unicity of the inverse yields $(A^{-1})^*=A^{-1}$. Furthermore, 
$$
\langle x, A^{-1} x\rangle=\langle Az,A^{-1} Az\rangle=\langle Az,z\rangle=\langle z,Az\rangle >0,
$$
if $x\neq 0$. Thus $A^{-1}$ is also pos.definite.

Using this definition we obtain 
$$
\langle x,B^*A^{-1} B x\rangle=\langle Bx,A^{-1} B x\rangle=\langle z,A^{-1}z\rangle. 
$$
Thus $B^*A^{-1}B$ is pos.semidefinite, if $B$ is invertable then pos.definite.

Comment: Thanks. It has been solved in the first comment. But your answer is more precise. I have used the symbol $\succ$, no $>$. I guess $\succ$ denotes for (semi)definite matrices only, am I right?

Comment: @noether Sorry, in the literature I have met the notation ">", your notation is new for me, but this does not mean anything. So I don't know the answer for your question about semidefiniteness.